# RSACryptoServiceProvider, SSLStream(OpenSSL) - Encrypt, Decrypt

Tags: criptografia, sslstream, rsa

Após a autenticação do servidor a partir do certificado gerado com openssl.

`sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName);`

A encriptação do dado por parte do cliente é feita da seguinte maneira:

```
        string messsage = "teste123.<EOF>";

        byte[] messageRSA = ConvertByte.GetBytes(messsage);

        RSACryptoServiceProvider asr = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);

        var publicKey = asr.ExportParameters(false);

        var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

        csp.ImportParameters(publicKey);

        messageRSA = csp.Encrypt(messageRSA, false);
```

E a informação é mandada através da sslStream da seguinte maneira para o servidor:

```
sslStream.Write(messageRSA);
sslStream.Flush();
```

Já no servidor, recebe a informação da seguinte maneira:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Com um método específico que eu mesmo criei, eu limpo esse buffer, de maneira que só tenha o valor que é mandado do lado do cliente, e gero uma chave privada para decriptar a informação da seguinte maneira:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider asr = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
var privateKey = asr.ExportParameters(true);
var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
csp.ImportParameters(privateKey);
decryptedMessage = FixBuffer(buffer);//método que limpa meu buffer e retorna um array de byte válido
decryptedMessage= csp.Decrypt(decryptedMessage, false);
```

Ao tentar decriptar, ele me devolve uma exceção do tipo `CryptographicException` dizendo `"Dados inválidos"`

E a pergunta é a seguinte, eu tenho que ter a public key que eu gerei do lado do cliente para quando for decriptar?
Porque pelo que percebi, ele gera esse erro a partir do momento que minha `privatekey` é diferente da `publickey` assim não decriptando a informação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necessário fazer a troca de chaves, depois da autenticação de ambas as partes, fracionando a public key em 2 partes(exponent e modulus), que são os únicos valores dentro da public key.